JSON-LD automatic StartDate and EndDate
my site have following JSON-LD code:
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "Event",
  "name": "Name of event",
  "startDate": "2024-04-07T15:00+03:00",
  "endDate": "2024-04-16T17:30+03:00",
  "eventStatus": "https://schema.org/EventMovedOnline",
  "eventAttendanceMode": "https://schema.org/OnlineEventAttendanceMode",
  "location": {
    "@type": "VirtualLocation",
    "url": "https://site"
  }
}
</script>

The event is repeated daily. Is it possible to automatically substitute today's date in "StartDate" and today's date + 1 day in "Enddate"?
I've read a lot of articles, but I haven't found anything like it.

What do you mean by "automatically"? Are you trying to come up with a json-ld object describing a repeating event series, or are you to write some javascript (clientside? serverside?) that generates an object for today's event?

Both options are suitable. The event is the same. Repeats every day. I’m just trying to come up with StartDate and EndDate are automatically filled with today’s date and today’s date + 1 day. Or should I generate a separate JSON-LD code every day and insert it into the  tag?

Whatever generates the JSON-LD needs to generate the values. What you likely need is to include a section in the schema that states how the event repeats: daily, weekly, last Sunday of the month, whatever.
